# How can I get Column number of the cursor in a TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface

I've got a multiline textBox that I would like to have a label on the form displaying the current line and column position of, as Visual Studio does.

I know I can get the line # with GetLineFromCharIndex, but how can I get the column # on that line?

(I really want the Cursor Position on that line, not 'column', per se)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int line = textbox.GetLineFromCharIndex(textbox.SelectionStart);
int column = textbox.SelectionStart - textbox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox.SelectionStart -
textBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox.SelectionStart))
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think you want the SelectionStart property.